# Could not load file or assembly App_Web_XXXXXXXX - ASP.Net - IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, web, web-config

I'm trying to upload my asp website to the server, it works fine in local
But I keep on getting this error

```
Line 1 :  <%@ page language="C#" autoeventwireup="true" inherits="Devis, App_Web_1sfq1hre" %>
Line 2 :
```

Here's My web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings/>
  <system.web>

    <compilation debug="false" >
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add assembly="System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        <add assembly="System.Xml.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>

    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" warningLevel="4" type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
        <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v2.0"/>
        <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false"/>
      </compiler>

    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Its seems your are uploading precompiled website and you have not copied bin directory. check that once. As far as i am concerned your web.config looks fine

Comment: Yes it's precompiled, I used visual studio's tool to publish the website.
I checked my FTP and there is the bin folder present

Comment: can you confirm app_web_xxxxxxxx file is there

Comment: yes, app_web_xxxxxxxx is there